# FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(FileName);

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-2.0

Can someone tell me what permission and file share does OpenRead methods reads file with.

I am trying this code,

```
FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(FileName);
```

But being suggested to use this code,

```
var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

So my question is, what File.OpenRead() uses by default if I don't provide other parameters.

I can't just change code as it's on production server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread.aspx)

> [public static FileStream OpenRead(string path)] is equivalent to the FileStream(String, FileMode,
>   FileAccess, FileShare) constructor overload with a FileMode value of
>   Open, a FileAccess value of Read and a FileShare value of Read.

Answer (score 6):

You can see decompiling :

```
public static FileStream OpenRead(string path)
{
      return new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
}
```

Which is the same as the second one :

```
public static FileStream Open(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
{
      return new FileStream(path, mode, access, share);
}
```

Comment: Why to decompile when it is well documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread.aspx)

Comment: And in addition You are sure 100% of the result. Documentation tend to be deprecated (To be fair, there it is unlikely with Microsoft Library). I Trust only the code!